# ASP.NET Application Daytime Release

Tags: asp.net

We have an Intranet with about 300 users whom actively use it thoroughly during the day.  We need to be able to release a precompiled version of the application during the day as users usually give us incorrect requirements and then need it that day.  At the moment we release a non-precompiled version and let the web server compile individual code-behind pages.  The problem is when we release things like App_Code, it hits the server big style.

Is it possible to release DLL's during the day without screwing up someone's actions on a web page?

Comment: You application pool will be restarted when you load new dlls but that is happening when you dump updated code files up to your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to second the "Get a second machine" sentiment, but I'm also going to offer a dodgy alternative.

You could always set up the website twice on the same machine. Assign 2 IP addresses to the machine and then assign one to each website. Finally set up load balancing across those two websites. This should allow you to direct user first to one site and then the other. I haven't tested this but I can't think of a reason that it wouldn't work.

Comment: Hmm, that actually sounds quite good.  I could test it next week.

Comment: @Kezzer just remember that for all purposes you have 2 separate deployments, so that means you can't rely on in process session, make sure to the machine key (so viewstate / auth tokens are valid across).

Comment: Do you really need different IPs? Just use different host-headers.

Comment: Okay, how about meeting in the middle.  What if I had two intranet sites, both exactly the same.  One was on "day" release, and the other is one which gets built during the day, so arbitrary release.  The arbitrary release (let's just say RC) can get built and released for applications that need immediate attention.  This way you get the best of both worlds without having to worry about redirecting ALL users, but instead point them to a different location for a single day?

Comment: That works. But for best performance you will need to set up load balancing across the two sites. This allows you to do a 'drainstop' on one site and have all users get redirected over to the second site without interruping their browsing experience. Please remember that this requires that you turn sticky sessions off.

Comment: I have zero experience in that, and wouldn't know where to start.  Could you direct me? This seems like our best option as resources won't cough up for another server, it's far too expensive (on the rack they're at least £5k for our setups)

Comment: Cheers, just for reference: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/gopenath/Page107182007032219AM/Page1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I disagree on the need for a second server to just a v. small downtime. Sure if you want No downtime you need the second server, but ...

what causes the big downtime + any issues you might be seeing is any stuff you have in there that depends on the app not restarting. AFAIK you can't prevent it from restarting when u change those, but you Can avoid the secondary effects that cause the extra downtimes or errors for the users.

Consider:

- Not using in-process session Or use
  in such a way that almost if not all
  of your site doesn't depend on having
  the stuff in there i.e. if you load
  some stuff that u can reload, u can
  do so afterwards
- Avoid having stuff that causes the app to be very load when starting
  i.e. static loading / or stuff that's
  loading at application_start
- Have a fixed machine key, since if not it will change with the app restart and all sort of stuff become invalid i.e. auth tokens, viewstate, etc

**Update 1:** Note that the items you have to do to reduce the "downtime" to seconds, its the same and/or relates to what you would have to do to use 2 servers.

So, just for that I would do that first, and if what you said in a comment isn't an overstatement and each minute (say 3 20 secs deployments) will lose you hundrens of pounds, I would add that second server.

Note that the reason for taking the app offline costing you hundreds of pounds might not be just the downtime, but all the lost sessions, forms submitted (viewstate), authentication invalidated, etc ... getting read of that - depending on how you do stuff, just gets the user a longer wait time when submitting something ... and if it didn't go through, they can re-submit and it will go through.

Comment: Yes hundreds of pounds was an exaggeration, but it would cause major backlash within the company as everyone is reliant on the system.  Walk around all the offices and you'll find everyone using it all the time.  The minute it goes down, no-one can work. It also retrieves real-time data which people rely on so that's another issue in itself.  Good answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have more than one server hosting the site?  If so you can take down one, update it, then put it back online.  Take down the second, update, etc..

Or if you only have one, and if this process only takes a few minutes, which it should, just post an app_offline.htm file saying "the site will be back in 2 minutes".

Comment: We can't take it offline, even for a minute.  It's doing stuff real-time and is used by every person in the company all day long.  Any downtime costs us hundreds of pounds per minute.  We only have one server (again, if I had the choice, I'd have two servers).

Comment: Perhaps this is a time to explain the need for a second server. Explain the need to update the code and the need to keep the site up and running.  If they say no to this, then you need to explain to them that when you do an update, some users will be affected.  Just the nature of the beast.

Comment: +1 to JackM.  Hundreds of pounds per minute, and you only have one server?  That's TheDailyWTF worthy!

Comment: while I disagree on the need of the second server for the original question (see my answer), the "hundreds of pounds per minute" does justify getting no downtime vs. just a few seconds ... unless that's an overstatement of course :P

Comment: Time is money, if you've got hundreds of users processing hundreds of clients and they get a few minutes down time then of course bad things happen.  It's an overstatement, obviously, but my point is we just can't have any downtime.

Comment: @Kezzer read my answer ... its usually not the < 30 secs that takes the app to be back up, its the lost auth tokens, session info with site features depending 100% on it never recycling, viewstates invalidated, etc. in other words, is the users having to start over what they were doing / including authenticating again + losing info what impacts you well above those < 30 secs, that doesn't have to be the case - you just need to program the features with that in mind and take some extra measures.

Answer (score 0):

In a single server environment like the one you are describing, then nope. You are going to have to wait until end of day to do deployments. 
Use this particular scenario to convince the powers that be at your organization that a second server is needed to do mid day updates and help mitigate downtime.

Comment: Could you not release individual DLL's?

Comment: No, the backend code files are always compiled into an external DLL.